# echo text file with multiple lines in php

Tags: php, file, echo, fread

I want print a text file in my php code but it give me the output without multiple lines!
think my txt file is this:
*( name = doc.txt )*

```
hello guys!
we are here
Lemon is with You!
```

now my code is:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("doc.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile, 100);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

now my problem is my output:

> hello guys! we are here Lemon is with You!

**I want it in multiple lines! how?**

Comment: It is already in that format. Since you are viewing in a browser, \n doesn't make sense to it. Use command line to view it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be to add the `<pre>` tag to your output:

```
echo "<pre>" . fread($myfile, 100) . "</pre>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it can not get whether its new line in file or not so you beed to use\n which produces new line
in doc.txt file

```
hello guys! \n
we are here \n
Lemon is with You!
```

then

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("doc.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile, 100);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: That won't help. The output is to the browser and the browser will ignore linebreaks unless you tag it with linebreaking tags, e.g. `<pre>` or `<div style="white-space: pre">`

Comment: Consider the user writing it with Enter